# Correlation of identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question about covariance or correlation of non-negative $X$ and $Y$ when they are identically distributed but not independent.
What can we say about the correlation defined by the formula

$\rho(X,Y) = \displaystyle \frac{E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]}{\sqrt{Var(X) Var(Y)}}$?

I know that the correlation is negative one when $Y = a - bX$ for some $a,b \geq 0$.
Can it hold in the case when $X \sim Y$?
Can $\rho(X,Y)$ be negative at all?
I am trying to construct the example with a negative covariance and would appreciate any advices.

Thank you in advance,
Vladimir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, and let $Y=1-X$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed and non-negative. The correlation coefficient is $-1$.

For a simpler example, let $X$ be the number of heads in $1$ toss of a fair coin, and $Y$ the number of tails.